# Qt compile issue w/ MySQL - Mac OS X

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, linker

Including mysql and creating a connection in Qt gives me compile problems:

```
MYSQL* conn;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
```

If I manually qmake and then make, I see that mysql isn't being properly linked:

```
qmake -o Makefile "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.1.54/include" "LIBS+=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.1.54/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a"
```

Undefined symbols:
  "_mysql_init", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What is the proper method for linking mysql to my Qt project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIBS+="-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.1.54/lib/mysql/ -lmysqlclient.a"

Also I'm not sure but Qt by default generates pbproj instead of Makefiles.

Comment: Almost right.  I was able to get the correct lib name by typing 'mysql_config --libs' This was the path I ended up using: LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.1.54/lib/mysql/ -lmysqlclient  Thanks for your help!